# WPF allow child user control to control specific keypress events of its parent

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

Using WPF .Net5.
I have  3 user controls.
VideoHost is a user control I made that hosts two separate child user controls I made called VideoControl & MediaElement. Videocontrol has buttons and slider that  control the actions of MediaElement. The buttons on Videocontrol have custom routed events that bubble up to VideoHost where they perform actions on MediaElement like Play stop pause etc.
My problem is I also want certain keypress functions to perform actions on MediaElement. Such as the Arrow keys. I want to put the code for keypress events in VideoControl, but it only works when VideoControl has the focus. How can I keep the code for Keypress inside VideoControl, allowing a hook-up in VideoHost via XML tags/properties/events that will deal with specific keys being pressed regardless if VideoControl has the focus or not.

Comment: Note that there can only be a single keyboard focus scope. Windows doesn't allow multiple keyboard focus scopes. You will always have to move the keyboard focus to the element that should receive the input. What you can do is to handle the keyboard input in your VideoControl and then let it raise  a RoutedEvent (e.g. Play) or execute a RoutedCommand (e.g., PlayCommand). Then let the parent VideoHost register event handlers/command bindings e.g., to handle the Play event/command. This seems to be the most reasonable solution, given that you were not very generous in providing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> VideoHost is a user control I made that hosts two separate child user controls I made called VideoControl & MediaElement

Based on this description, your `.xaml` is similar to this..

```
<UserControl x:Class="VideoHost" KeyDown="VideoHost_OnKeyDown">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <views:MediaElement x:Name="MediaElement"/>
        <views:VideoControl x:Name="VideoControl"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl x:Class="VideoHost">
```

You can handle `KeyDown` event in `VideoHost` and invoke the functions that are in `VideoControl`

```
private void VideoHost_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // MediaElement.InvokeMyKeypressCode(e);
    VideoControl.InvokeMyKeypressCode(e);
}
```